# Backbone 404 errror if C# controller is changed to ApiController

Tags: c#, backbone.js, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm trying to learn .Net and backbone.js. I'm working on a very simple project; it's for listing all the recipients and also updating their addresses and stuff. I have a RecipientsController that just gets the list of the recipients from the database. Here's the controller.

```
public ActionResult GetAllRecipients()
{
    var recipients = dbContext.Recipients.ToList();
    return Json(recipients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

This works fine; my backbone app can receive the JSON and will display them properly. But I couldn't get the edit(PUT) to work. So, I googled about it and came across a tutorial that used ApiController instead of Controller. I decided to try it, so I changed the Controller to ApiController.

```
public IEnumerable<Recipients> GetAllRecipients()
    {

        return dbContext.Recipients.AsEnumerable();

    }
```

When I try with ApiController, backbone gives me 404 error. I don't understand why.

This is my

```
HomeController: 
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Recipients()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

And I have two Views (Index and Recipients) both are under Views/Home. 
This is my ActionLink:

```
<li>
     <a id="recipients">@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Recipients", "Home")</a>
</li>
```

Now, with ApiController, if I change the ActionLink from Home to Recipients, Recipients to GetRecipients, and move the View (Recipients) from under Home to a new folder Recipients, then it works but it doesn't use my backbone views. I'm really confused. Can someone please explain this for me so I can understand? Since I'm learning, I had hard time understanding some of the descriptions I found online (it was too advanced for me), but also I'm not sure if the explanation I found was what I needed anyway.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Here's my route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Recipients", 
        "{Controller}/{action}",
        new { Controller = "Recipients", action = "GetAllRecipients", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
    );
```

Comment: What is in your routes?

Comment: @PatrickHuber I added the routes

Comment: I think it may be due to convention. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api. You shouldn't have to map the route specifically, the convention of WebApi is that {Method}All{Controller} maps to METHOD : /{controller}. I think you need to add a MapHttpRoute as shown in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone will only perform PUT if model has an ID attribute, this is the convention of backbone to knows how to POST or SAVE data.

Probably, backbone is trying to post data on server, and it is returning 404 because you don't have an action to POST.
When you get data to your model, try to return from server an ID Atribute.

Imagine that you're returning this class on GET.
example:

```
public class testDTO()
{   
   long ID {get;set;}
   string Something { get;set;}

}
```

Take a read http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

Hope it helps.